# Why does my git merge now delete files?

Tags: git, merge

I have a product which I have released which is in the `MASTER` branch. I've branched off Master to create a `BUGFIX` branch to fix issues found in production. I also have a `DEVELOPMENT` branch which I'm using to work on new feature requests.

So when a bug is logged, I fix it in `BUGFIX`, then when deployed, I merge it into `MASTER` and also `DEVELOPMENT` branches so everything is up to date. This has been working fine for a while now. Today, when I try and merge `BUGFIX` into `DEVELOPMENT`, I get merge conflicts and it wants to delete the new files that I have in my solution which have been added as part of the new feature requests in `DEVELOPMENT`.

Why has it started doing this and how can I rectify it?

Edit: added image.

[image: graph]

Comment: Are you able to draw the branches graph?

Comment: @dgiugg graph added to post.

Comment: I assume `BUGFIX` is `snaglist` shown in the image. I count 21 commits in your graph between `snaglist` and `development`'s HEADs, as their nearest common ancestor is "Removed CSV helper library" more than halfway down the image. It's hard to tell you why this conflict is happening without having any idea what the content of those 21 commits was.

Comment: @DanLowe Yes BUGFIX is snaglist. The 21 commits to DEVELOPMENT is work towards the next feature release. It says "Merge branch 'master' into 'snaglist'. Did I make an error there? I was supposed to have merged SNAGLIST into MASTER as SNAGLIST has the changes in it I wanted merged into MASTER. Or is this a syntax quirk on part of Git?

Comment: Unless I am reading the image wrong, `snaglist` and `master` (and their remote versions on `origin` are all pointing at the same commit already. It is `development` that needs to merge in somehow, isn't it?

Comment: And yes, it does appear the most recent merge was merging master into snaglist, not the other way around.

Comment: I cannot merge snaglist into development because its deleting the additional files I've created for the next feature release. I've had to pull the individual files into development from snaglist for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

When start merge, which are you standing?

if is BUGFIX, Git will delete your file that you have added in DEVELOP because now your code in BUGFIX is base.

Opposite, if you are standing on DEVELOP and merge to BUGFIX, i think result will be ok.

Summary, result will different when you standing on different branchs.

Comment: I'm doing it the same way I was previously. Checkout development and merge bugfix in.